# How Electric field is generated inside wire when a voltage source is connected to it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I have found by my searches that the electric field inside wire is generated by the positive or negative charges accumulated at the surface of wire.

My question is, Why do charge get accumulated on surface of wire? And the second thing is, How this charge redistribution creates an electric field inside wire that is perpendicular to area of cross-section of wire?

Third thing, How increasing the area of cross-section of wire to twice makes the generated electric flux inside wire also twice?

Comment: I would recommend removing the third question. It is not closely related to the other two. It would also be better if you could focus the first two into one overall question.

Comment: Sorry it is necessary to be included otherwise I would have to ask another question and people may give different ideas in that another question. Bug I need a single idea that can explain it all.

Comment: "Why do charge get accumulated on surface of wire?" Are you referring to a charged conductor?

Comment: @BobD  No, i am not referring to a charged conductor. The charge redistribution happens inside wire when voltage is applied across it. Positive charge get accumulated at surface near positive terminal and negative charge gets accumulated at surface near negative terminals. It generates electric field inside wire to produce current.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss. My comment was directed to the OP, not you.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss said “it is necessary to be included”. Shouldn’t you let the OP, Arsenal Creation, make that call.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, Why do charge get accumulated on surface of wire? And the second thing is, How this charge redistribution creates an electric field inside wire that is perpendicular to area of cross-section of wire?

When a circuit is first closed there are some initial transient currents that last only for a very brief time. These transient currents can point in any direction, but you can always decompose them into a longitudinal component along the length of the wire and a transverse component that lies within the cross section of the wire. The continuity equation says $$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla \cdot \vec J = 0$$ For the transverse component, since the current cannot go past the edge of the conductor $\nabla \cdot \vec J$ is very large right at the surface. This means that $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ is also very large at the surface so charge accumulates rapidly at the surface. This surface charge accumulation produces its own E-field which acts in a direction that opposes the transverse current that produced the charge accumulation. Thus these transient transverse currents decay very quickly as the surface charge forms (also very quickly).

After the transients, the transverse current is eliminated and we are left only with the longitudinal current. Thus only the component of the current in the direction perpendicular to the cross-section remains since that is the only direction where $\nabla \cdot \vec J$ can be 0 in steady state.

Comment: so do you mean that only the components of electric field perpendicular to the cross-section are left and other field vectors parallel to the cross-section gets cancelled and you get net electric field in that specific direction such that an electron should follow the correct path to reach the end of the wire which is at the higher potential than the other end?

Comment: You talked about the electric field created by surface charge stopping the transverse current. But how is there an electric field generated perpendicular to cross-section of wire? The fields released by battery cannot bend throughout wire if the wire has bents. So how is there an perpendicular component inside wire also can you equate it to $E$, where $E = V/L$ or (Voltage / Length)

Comment: @TejasDahake yes, that is correct. The combination of Maxwell’s equations (including the continuity equation) and Ohms law leads to that result.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss by Ohms law the longitudinal current and the longitudinal E field are essentially the same, but let’s allow the OP to weigh in and see if it is unclear to them

Comment: @Dale I am the OP.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss that is very confusing. You should merge the accounts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts